# Magento 2 Embedding PHTML in CMS page

Tags: magento2, cms, phtml

Having a issue with figuring out how to get this working.

**file path for custom template:**

> app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/custom/custom.phtml

**In my CMS page, I have it written as:**

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="VENDOR_THEME::custom/custom.phtml"}}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your **phtml** file with block in **layout.xml file** and then call it same way.

**Like below example of layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="Vendor_Test::test.phtml"></block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Then in your cms page :**

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Test::test.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, but now im getting this error message : 
We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email.

Comment: @Jru-Ski well thats your custom theme override issue , thats not related to call phtml file in block .check the email template or something which you have overriden